# Generating sets with exactly one mutual element

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I have a quite interesting task. I need to generate all $n$-element sets, such that every two of them have exactly one mutual element. There are $m$ elements to choose from and can be assumed, that this number is sufficient.
Example for $n = 4 \wedge m=11$:

$$\{1,2,3,4\}\\
\{1,5,6,7\}\\
\{8,2,5,9\}\\
\{1,9,10,11\}$$

I'm not quite sure, if there is one solution to that problem.

Do you have any hints of math theorems or algorithms, that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is obviously a solution, given by taking all the sets with the element $1$ in common, then placing the remaining elements in triples. With $n=4,m=11$ we get:
$$\{1,2,3,4\},\quad \{1,5,6,7\},\quad \{1,8,9,10\}$$
and, additionally, we can take the sets:
$$\{11,2,5,8\},\quad\{11,3,6,9\},\quad \{11,4,7,10\}$$
corresponding to the following combinatorial design:
[image]
associated with some lines in the projective space $\mathbb{P}_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$. The problem, in general, is equivalent to finding a maximal clique in a [generalized Kneser graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph) $KG_{m,n,1}$.